# how do i use Latent Dirichlet Allocation with python for my dissertation topic on Trend Analysis of IoT vulnerability

Tags: python, json, analytics, lda, trend

i am a beginner in python and i need to perform an analysis with python using the Latent Dirichlet Allocation on the VARIoT dataset, can i get a step by step script on how to go about it and if their is an article of previous work on this.

I tried importing pandas so i can create the dataframe but wheni tried to run my saved file it didnt recognize the file, i dont know if i didnt write the correct script because i dont know anything about programming, i just started to glance through it because of my dissertation so its been difficult to grasp given the time frame i have.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.